# Code::blocks, define default input

Tags: c++, input, codeblocks

I want to execute in Code::blocks  IDE program providing standard input.

Say

```
                                                                                              #include <iostream>
#include <cmath>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    double a;
    double b;

    cout << "Side one\n";
    cin >> a;
    cout << "Side two\n";
    cin >> b;

    cout << "Result :" << sqrt(a*a + b*b) << endl;
}
```

With arguments "a" and "b"  , provided in file:

Say:

```
2 4
```

I could do that in bash, compiling and then:

```
"./my_compiled_program < ./myinput"
```

I simply want to have, file with argument (standard input) in code::blocks.

How can I do this? 
PS: The "set program's arguments" unfortunately don't works[image: Set program's argument]

Comment: On your screenshot you provide '2 4' as program args while you should do `< ./myinput`

Comment: I am not sure I understand what your trying to do. Do you want to force a & b to be specific numbers? Or are you asking something else?

Comment: @aleguna, Where in code::blocks I can do "< ./myinput" ?

Comment: @bluesm, in "set program's arguments"

Comment: @Robert Just to to execute without asking for values, but getting one after the other, from file, or another source.

Answer (score 4):

Thanks to @aleguna:

We should make file in folder where is the file we want to compile and execute:
[image: Place input next to source code]

And then add the `< ./input` to program arguments, where `input` is the name of file we placed next to source code.

[image: In code::blocks]

Thank you @aleguna.

Comment: this doesn't work on windows, any ideas of how to do what op says?